# Bootsfaces FacesMessage always displays summary and detail

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

By doing this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new    FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,msg.getMessageResourceWithParams("admini.client.search.save.ok",
                    new Object[]{clientOnSearch.getFirstName()+"  "+clientOnSearch.getLastName()}),null));
```

I am only expecting to see the Summary on the interface since I put the detail set to null.

But it displays the same messsage twice, on the summary and details.

`Client Bruno Laaaalapa was successfully added Client Bruno Laaaalapa was successfully added`

On the xhtml I have:

```
<b:row>
    <b:column>
        <b:messages/>
    </b:column>
</b:row>
```

Is anything missing on it ?

Thanks

Comment: It may not be totally related to your question, but you can simplify your code with our `FacesMessages` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have found a little misbehaviour there, normally `b:messages`' detail shouldn't be shown on default (default is documented to be `false`, but is `true` instead, [we will fix that with 0.8.2](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/352)).

However, you can explicitly hide the detail by specifying:

```
 <b:messages showDetail="false"/>
```

You could also opt for showing the detail, but not the summary:

```
 <b:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="false"/>
```

Comment: In fact, I've done a major rework on `<b:message />` and `<b:messages />` in BootsFaces 0.8.2. Things should work a lot smoother with the new version.